# Meu app está pegando as mesmas configurações mesmo após usar finish

Tags: android, firebase

Sou iniciante em android e estou desenvolvendo um app de chat em que eu conecto duas pessoas com base nas preferências delas. Quando uma das duas pessoas encerra a conversa e resolve voltar para a fila escolhendo a mesma opção de antes(exemplo: ajudar), ela acaba sendo redirecionada ao mesmo usuário de antes. No meu código eu usei finish para finalizar a tela de chat quando ela escolhesse sair da conversa, mas eu não sei exatamente onde estou errando. Existe algo que eu possa fazer antes de dar finish que impeça o meu app de pegar as configurações do usuário com que ele conversou ao entrar novamente na fila?

Classe usada:

FilaPareamento(Aqui o usuário está na fila aguardando alguem): [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/M7unYHXR)

Eu tentei recarregar a activity antes de entrar na fila novamente utilizando recreate e abrindo uma nova intent para a mesma página. Mas o meu app trava com isso. Não sei o que fazer. 
Muito obrigada a quem puder me dar uma luz!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema! Eu havia criado um eventListener para pesquisar outros usuários com quem conversar e quando achava um eu abria uma nova tela de conversa sem fechar esse eventlistener. Então mesmo que eu encerrasse a conversa, já havia um eventlistener antigo aberto que me redirecionava sempre ao mesmo usuário de antes se ele clicasse em entrar na fila de novo.

Basicamente para resolver o problema eu precisei remover o eventlistener dentro do método onStop. Vou deixar o método aqui!

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (this.isFinishing() || this.isDestroyed()){
        /*Se a activity foi fechada então remove o eventlistener*/

        if (this.opcao == 1){
            filaFirebaseTeAjudo.removeEventListener(valueMeAjudateAjudo);

        } else if (this.opcao == 2){
            filaFirebaseMeAjuda.removeEventListener(valueTeAjudoMeAjuda);

        } else {
            filaFirebaseAmbos.removeEventListener(ambos);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "onStop-saiu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```